# cURL and local storage

Tags: php, curl, local-storage

I need to use cURL to get data from a website but I need to include the session token in my request header. The problem is, the session token is stored in the browser's local storage. Since cURL is not a web browser, how can I get the session token?

EDIT:
Here's my code:

```
define('COOKIE_FILE','cookie.txt');
$url = 'https://website.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($curl_error || $http_code !== 200) {
    return "Error!\ncUrl: $curl_error\nHTTP code: $http_code\nResult: $result";
} else {
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code, the question itself is way too broad

Comment: @Nordenheim please see my edit. When I visit 'https://website.com' in a browser, it stores the session token in the browser's local storage. I need to get the session token so I can pass it on my next cURL request.

Comment: Is this process triggered by a browser, or is it completely unattended?

Comment: @msanford it is completely unattended with no user interaction. It would have been easier if the website stores their session token in the cookie but instead, they store it in the browser's local storage.

Comment: You can't have access to the localstorage, it's client only.

Comment: @Eric yes, I figured. I was thinking if other developers have some sort of a workaround on this.